GE Electric cooktop stove, all 4 elements quit at the same time
My GE glass cooktop countertop stove. Stopped working. While cooking all 4 elements where on. Suddenly the stove just quit and hasn't come back on. The stove just died. I did all checks suggested by other, unplugg for 30 sec. Check breakers etc. The breaker was not thrown. Model # Jcp346bm2bb

Recheck the breaker.  If not the breaker, you have a loose/broken/burnt wire.  If not the breaker, keep the breaker off till checked or fixed.  Cooktops use a lot of power, so a wire not correct can do a lot of damage, like fire or shock you bad.

Nothing works on the stove, no displays, no control lights, no nothing?

On some breakers it is not very visible they are thrown,
push them to one side then to the other side to reset

This is correct. But for the OP @Tina: if the breaker refuses to stay in the "on" position, then there's something wrong inside the stove or the wiring, and you need professional help.
